# Listbox in Grid will not resize

Tags: c#, xaml, listbox

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="300" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Rectangle Fill="#8686EA" Grid.Column="0" />
    <Rectangle Fill="#FFFFE1" Grid.Column="1" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="NickNameBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,22,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Nickname" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="NickName" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="84,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="109"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="ChannelBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,59,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Channel" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="Channel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="84,47,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="109"/>
    <Button x:Name="JoinButton" Content="Join" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="198,47,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Grid Grid.Column="1">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="630" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Rectangle Fill="white" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="10,27,0,100" />
        <!--<Rectangle Fill="white" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="6,10,71,196" />-->
        <Grid Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,0,0,196">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Rectangle Fill="#8686EA" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="0" Grid.Row="0" Margin="10,0,0,0" />
            <Rectangle Fill="#CCCCFF" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="0" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10,0,0,-5" RenderTransformOrigin="0.505,0.719" Grid.RowSpan="2" />
            <ListBox x:Name="listBox" Grid.Row="2" Margin="10,10,0,0"  VerticalAlignment="Top" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
                <ListBox.Items>
                    <ListBoxItem Content="Tewl"/>
                    <ListBoxItem Content="Ryu"/>
                    <ListBoxItem Content="Clint"/>
                    <ListBoxItem Content="Bak3r"/>
                    <ListBoxItem Content="sm0kex"/>
                    <ListBoxItem Content="Jack"/>
                    <ListBoxItem Content="Bam"/>
                    <ListBoxItem Content="Jay"/>
                    <ListBoxItem Content="Tewl"/>
                    <ListBoxItem Content="Ryu"/>
                    <ListBoxItem Content="Clint"/>
                    <ListBoxItem Content="Bak3r"/>
                    <ListBoxItem Content="sm0kex"/>
                    <ListBoxItem Content="Jack"/>
                    <ListBoxItem Content="Bam"/>
                    <ListBoxItem Content="Jay"/>
                    <ListBoxItem Content="Tewl"/>
                    <ListBoxItem Content="Ryu"/>
                    <ListBoxItem Content="Clint"/>
                    <ListBoxItem Content="Bak3r"/>
                    <ListBoxItem Content="sm0kex"/>
                    <ListBoxItem Content="Jack"/>
                    <ListBoxItem Content="Bam"/>
                    <ListBoxItem Content="Jay"/>
                </ListBox.Items>
            </ListBox>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

[updated listbox in full mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2qzF.png)
[updated nicklist resized still wont expand listbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXTmz.png)

this was reupdated for Chris W.  this has the entire code..my problem must be higher I really hate width/height/margins ..

Comment: Remove the hard set Height, and negative Margin on your ListBox for starters.....Then change "auto" to "*" on your last RowDefinition.

Comment: @Chris W. thank you for the support... I made the changes you told me after modifying since last post...I still cannot seem to get a full listbox screen when the window isnt maximized [code]

Comment: Set VerticalContentAlignment=Stretch / VerticalAlignment=Stretch, if that doesn't do it then you have a conflict higher in your layout structure.

Comment: it must be my upper layout

Comment: @ChrisW.if you can look once more i added the entire xaml code..please

Comment: Ok one sec, oh and @their name is enough to get someone a notification to them, no need for names in headers. :)

Comment: @chrisW. anything you could find wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your margins and rowspans and unnecessary clutter are just going to cause you more headaches in the future. If you don't mind I just went ahead and re-wrote what you had there and made it all so it would respond to whatever resizing and stuff you do. See changes made below which includes your answer. If it were me I would do something more like this;

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="300" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="200" Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <!-- Left Pane -->
    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="26"/>
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiBold"/>
                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right"/>
            </Style>
        </Grid.Resources>

        <!-- These didn't seem to have a purpose, so commenting out for now.
        <Rectangle Fill="#8686EA" Grid.Column="0" />
        <Rectangle Fill="#FFFFE1" Grid.Column="1" />
        -->

        <TextBlock x:Name="NickNameBlock" Text="Nickname"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" x:Name="NickName" 
                 TextWrapping="Wrap" Text=""/>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" x:Name="ChannelBlock" Text="Channel" />
        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="Channel" 
                 TextWrapping="Wrap" Text=""/>

        <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" x:Name="JoinButton" Content="Join"
                MinWidth="50" Margin="0,5"/>

    </Grid>
    <!-- End Left Pane -->

    <!-- Center Pane -->
    <Rectangle Grid.Column="1" Fill="white"/>
    <!-- End Center Pane -->

    <!-- Right Pane -->
    <Grid Grid.Column="2" Background="#CCCCFF">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Rectangle Fill="#8686EA"/>

        <ListBox x:Name="listBox" Grid.Row="2" 
                 ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
            <ListBox.Items>
                <ListBoxItem Content="Tewl"/>
                <ListBoxItem Content="Ryu"/>
                <ListBoxItem Content="Clint"/>
                <ListBoxItem Content="Bak3r"/>
                <ListBoxItem Content="sm0kex"/>
                <ListBoxItem Content="Jack"/>
                <ListBoxItem Content="Bam"/>
                <ListBoxItem Content="Jay"/>
                <ListBoxItem Content="Tewl"/>
                <ListBoxItem Content="Ryu"/>
                <ListBoxItem Content="Clint"/>
                <ListBoxItem Content="Bak3r"/>
                <ListBoxItem Content="sm0kex"/>
                <ListBoxItem Content="Jack"/>
                <ListBoxItem Content="Bam"/>
                <ListBoxItem Content="Jay"/>
                <ListBoxItem Content="Tewl"/>
                <ListBoxItem Content="Ryu"/>
                <ListBoxItem Content="Clint"/>
                <ListBoxItem Content="Bak3r"/>
                <ListBoxItem Content="sm0kex"/>
                <ListBoxItem Content="Jack"/>
                <ListBoxItem Content="Bam"/>
                <ListBoxItem Content="Jay"/>
            </ListBox.Items>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
    <!-- End Right Pane -->

</Grid>
```

Result:

[image]

Hope this helps, cheers.

Comment: PS If you're actually making an IRC app from start to finish (stressing the part on finishing it) we can talk offline and I'd possibly be willing to donate some time to a cool UI for ya to expand my portfolio using it as an example. Except I end up doing far too much free work for people who don't finish their end which makes it pointless for me to help. Good luck either way! :)

Comment: thank you very much @ChrisW. no we are extremly dedicated to finishing this... this is for an up and coming chat server   www.irc7.com   with an almost identical engine as original msn chat...we just need to make a client now and rid ourselves of the msnchat ocx nobody wants to use anymore... i would love any help you can offer for gui design

Answer (score 0):

Setting the last RowDefinition to *, removing the margins and changing the VerticalAlignment=Top seemed to work for me.

```
    <Grid Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,0,0,0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Rectangle Fill="#8686EA" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="0" Grid.Row="0" Margin="10,0,0,0" />
        <Rectangle Fill="#CCCCFF" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="0" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10,0,0,0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.505,0.719" />
        <ListBox x:Name="listBox" Grid.Row="2" Margin="10,0,0, 0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <ListBox.Items>
                <ListBoxItem Content="Tewl"/>
                <ListBoxItem Content="Ryu"/>
                <ListBoxItem Content="Clint"/>
                <ListBoxItem Content="Bak3r"/>
                <ListBoxItem Content="sm0kex"/>
                <ListBoxItem Content="Jack"/>
                <ListBoxItem Content="Bam"/>
                <ListBoxItem Content="Jay"/>
            </ListBox.Items>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: it must be my upper heirarchy